# What elements can block WPF dependency property inheritance?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

My WPF App attaches a custom inherited dependency property (from a behavior) to my main application view.  The idea is to pass this property (which never changes once the app is running) all the way down to some very nested controls that need it

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainWindow"
        core:SystemBehavior.SystemService="{Binding MySystem}"
```

It works well.   So far, all of my controls have been able to access this data

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                Path=(core:SystemBehavior.SystemService).Units}"
```

But there's this ominous sentence in the [MS documentation about Property Value Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance)  that gives me pause.

> However, property value inheritance can bridge this gap in the logical
>   tree and can still pass inherited values through, so long as the
>   inheritable property was registered as an attached property ***and no
>   deliberate inheritance-blocking boundary (such as a Frame) is
>   encountered.***

(emphasis added by me)

So my question is:  What elements (besides a frame) can "block" dependency property inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any documentation that explicitly answers the question.

I searched [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/InheritanceBehavior.cs,180b2f8e640a4a57,references) to come up with this list:

- Frame
- Page
- DocumentReference
- FixedPage
- PageContent